# Fabric js inserting new text not visible while image selected

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

This is a tshirt design application based on fabric js. The problem is the text insert and edit works fine. when we add an image and then we add a text while the image is selected the text is not visible (probably size 0). But after couple of font change it works fine.

[Here is the app preview](http://www.parableu.com/george/tshirt/preview5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have gone through your code and i found that once if you are adding any art or picture and you select it on canvas, font color is changing to white, so while setting 'fcolor' property on object:selected event, you need to first check if selected object is of type 'text' or not, if it is of type 'text' than and only than you have to set 'fcolor' property

Comment: Thank you. I thought about checking object type but dont know how. How to check object type whether image or text?

Comment: you can check type of an object by this line : 
canvas.getActiveObject().type = "i-text"